# ¿Como conectar DevExpress y visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, devexpress

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que tengo que hacer reportes con DevExpress pero no se como conectarlo, uso como Base de datos postgresql
¿me podrían decir como conectarla?

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask].. DevExpress son controles, a que te referis con como conectarlos? de seguro en su pagina tienen miles de ejemplos..

Comment: es que quiero hacer un reporte de una factura, pero la verdad no se como usar DevExpress

Comment: Entonces nada mejor que leer la documentacion de DevExpress y sobre todo de los componentes que vayas a usar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente, utilizo los productos de DevExpress para WinForms, y no veo ninguna dificultad para conectar, sus controles son muy flexibles, puede hacerlo a través de un asistente de configuración en el reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
O directamente en el código:

- [SqlDataSource - Cómo cambiar los parámetros de conexión en tiempo de ejecución](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T291969/sqldatasource-how-to-change-connection-parameters-at-runtime)
- [Cómo crear una cadena de conexión correcta para proveedores de XPO](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/k18445/how-to-create-a-correct-connection-string-for-xpo-providers)

En su caso con `PostgreSql`:

```
PostgreSqlConnectionProvider: Postgres
XpoProvider=Postgres;Server=127.0.0.1;User 
ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;Database=MyDatabase;Encoding=UNICODE
```

Ha intentado buscar su problema en el [Soporte DevExpress](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/)?, considero que es el primer punto de partida que debe tener.

En caso de **no tener la licencia vigente para soporte**, de todos modos, en el [Soporte DevExpress](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/), tiene una amplia lista de información, de preguntas de otros usuarios que con solo buscar, puede ser de mucha utilidad independientemente de no tener una licencia vigente. De todos modos aquí le dejo un enlace directo como punto de partida:

[Crear un informe de la A a la Z](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2440/get-started-with-devexpress-reporting/create-a-report-from-a-to-z)

Esta sección contiene tutoriales paso a paso que muestran cómo crear un informe:

> Lección 1: agregar un informe y vincularlo a los datos
>
> Lección 2 - Crear un diseño de detalle maestro
>
> Lección 3 - Usar parámetros para filtrar datos en un informe
>
> Lección 4: proporcionar navegación a un informe
>
> Lección 5: proporcionar interactividad a un informe
>
> Lección 6 - Agrupar datos de informes y calcular resúmenes
>
> Lección 7 - Personalizar la apariencia del informe

Como podrá comprender, su **centro de soporte es en inglés**, pero esto no impide que pueda traducirlas para comprenderlas, usando un traductor de su preferencia.

Comment: me aparece un error diciendo que no se puede conectar a la base de datos

Comment: @CarlosFernandez revise su cadena de conexión, demás debería proporcionar mas detalles, de **que error** le muestra, ya que no lo estoy viendo, en todas las informaciones que le he proporcionado en mi respuesta, puede encontrar el enlace adecuado para encontrar una solución

Comment: el erro que me manda es   Mensaje de error: Could not find assembly 'Npgslq'

Comment: @CarlosFernandez ese error no esta relacionado directamente con DevExpress,  Instale la versión 4.1.1 hacer `npgsql Install-Package Npgsql -Version 4.1.1`

Comment: @CarlosFernandez dale un vistazo a la respuesta de Dennis en [esta pregunta](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q130347/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-npgsql-version-1-0-0-0), además vea esto [PostgreSQL Connection String Error](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T118394/postgresql-connection-string-error)